# Android Kotlin Dynamic RatingBar - setting number of stars

Tags: android, kotlin, dynamically-generated, ratingbar

I am trying to dynamically through Kotlin add a list of products with ratingbars for their ratings.  I was able to add the ratingbars; however, the rating bars show 7 stars. I want 5 stars.  I tried using *.numStars = 5 but I still get 7 stars as shown in the pic below for Popcorn.

```
    fun populateUIWithRatingInfo() {

    for (orderItem in orderItemsList) {
        val dynamicTextView = TextView(requireContext())
        dynamicTextView.text = orderItem.title
        binding.productRatingList.addView(dynamicTextView)

        val dynamicRatingBar = RatingBar(requireContext())
        dynamicRatingBar.numStars= 5
        binding.productRatingList.addView(dynamicRatingBar)
    }

}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer: The answer marked with the check mark is correct below. Since it doesn't describe how to do that dynamically, I will post a snippet of code that shows how to set width to wrap-content of the rating bar.

```
dynamicRatingBar.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar#setNumStars(int)), you need to set the `layout_width` property to `wrap_content`

> public void setNumStars (int numStars):
> Sets the number of stars to show. In order for these to be shown properly, it is recommended the layout width of this widget be wrap content.